# having issue on getting real image from s3 after uploading using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Hi I have uploaded image using this code on s3 .

first I am getting image from a

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)  //which is some png data
```

then uploading to s3

```
        s3 = get_s3_resource_client()
        bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
        key = '/image/' + file_name + '.png'
        bucket.put_object(Key=key, Body=io.BytesIO(output_image.data), ContentType='text/png')
```

and when I am trying to get url of this image from s3 by clicking on open Image here

[image]

I get this instead of my original image getting this string

[image]

I don't want this I want my original image here. how I can achieve this?

Comment: The content type for `.png` would be `image/png`, not `text/png`.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi okay let me test. other then this my code is fine ?

Comment: The key should not be `'/image/' + file_name + '.png'`. It should not begin with forward slash. Also, using `response.text` from the GET of the PNG sounds completely wrong for a binary response. Use `response.content`.